# Lightning add campaign members via report (Spring 17)

Tags: lightning, campaign, campaign-member

In Salesforce Classic it is possible to add leads or contacts via a report to a campaign.
In early releases of Salesforce Lightning, that was not possible.

Is it possible to add leads or contacts via a report to a campaign in Spring 17?
 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With the Winter 17 release, you can mass add leads and contacts from list views. [Etisbew](https://www.etisbew.com/salesforce.html) also introducing a new campaign influence object that will give you API access and support for additional models.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But. Is it possible to add leads or contacts via a report to a campaign in Spring 17?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can..

```
From a report that returns lead, contact, or person account records, click Add to Campaign.

If the Add to Campaign button is disabled, modify your report to return fewer than 50,000 records.
Enter the name of a campaign.
Select a member status for the new members.
Choose whether members already associated with the campaign keep their status. If you want, update their status with the one you selected for new members.
Click Add to Campaign.
Review the confirmation screen.
Click Done to return to the report.
```

Comment: Thanks again. As soon as I have tried this I will accept your answer.

Comment: that seems to apply to classic only